# I want to make Sort program using File input/output with C language

Tags: c, file, sorting, file-io, mergesort

I want to make 'Merge sort' Program.
When i started it "arr.txt" and "brr.txt" are just data and "result.txt" is result of merge sort (arr.txt+brr.txt) .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void merge_sort(int num)
{

     FILE *fp1,*fp2,*fp3;               // fp1 is arr.txt, fp2 is brr.txt, and fp3 is result.txt

     int i, j, point_one=0, point_two=0;

     char a[num], b[num], c[num];

     fp1=fopen("arr.txt","r");
     fp2=fopen("brr.txt","r");
     fp3=fopen("result.txt","w");

     fscanf(fp1, "%s", a);
     fscanf(fp2, "%s", b);

     for(i=0;i<num;i++)
     {
           if(a[point_one]>b[point_two])
           {
               fprintf(fp3, b[point_two]);
               point_two++;
           }
           else
           {
               fprintf(fp3, a[point_one]);
               point_one++;
           }
     }


     fclose(fp1);
     fclose(fp2);
     fclose(fp3);
}

int main(void)
{

    FILE *fp_one,*fp_two;

    char *arr;

    char *brr;

    int num;

    fp_one=fopen("arr.txt","w");

    fp_two=fopen("brr.txt","w");

    printf("input array size :");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    arr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*num);
    brr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*num);

    printf("input arr :" );
    scanf("%s", arr);
    printf("input brr :");
    scanf("%s", brr);

    fprintf(fp_one, arr);
    fprintf(fp_two, brr);

    merge_sort(num);

    fclose(fp_one);
    fclose(fp_two);
    free(arr);
    free(brr);
    return 0;
}
```

But, in this code, I can't play sorting. Please help me

++
if array size is 5, arr.txt's contents are "acfj",and brr.txt's contents are "bdgh",
the result.txt's contents are "abcdfgh"

Comment: Two things: First the data you write to the files `arr.txt` and `brr.txt` may actually not have been flushed when you later try to read the files. Secondly, what is your input, and what is your expected and actual output? Please edit your question to input the input and output.

Comment: If your `num` variable is `3`, and you input e.g. `"acfj"`, then you have a buffer overflow, which leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: oh.. it's my mistake. i edited it now

Comment: You're trying to output data one `char` at a time, so you either need to use `fputc` instead of `fprintf` or - if you need badly `fprintf` - supply appropriate format to it: `fprintf(fp3,"%c",b[point_two]);`.

Comment: You should have separate routines for: 1. reading data into memory; 2: sorting in-memory data; 3. outputting sorted array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should close `fp_one` and `fp_two` before calling `merge_sort()`. Otherwise the previous output may haven't been flushed into file yet.

According to your test input, you tried to store 5 characters into 3-element character array (don't forget the `'\0'` character terminating a string). This leads to buffer overflow, which in turn leads to undefined behavior.

Yet another problem: in `merge_sort()`, when either `point_one` or `point_two` reaches the end of string, the next comparison always pick `'\0'` which is smaller than all other characters.

Comment: @user3340343 "it still doesn't work" is not enough for diagnosis. What's your input? What's your expected output? And what's your current output?

Comment: sorry for my mistake .. and if array size is 3, arr.txt's contents are "acfj",and brr.txt's contents are "bdgh", the result.txt's contents are "abcdfgh"

Comment: The OP will not reach the point of either `point_one` or `point_two` being the index of either string terminator (or more), as the loop just runs for five times. And besides, writing a zero to a file doesn't terminate the output, it just writes a zero to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. The first is that you don't print the letters correctly. The `fprintf` function expects the second argument to be a *string*, but you pass it a *single character*. The compiler should be screaming warnings about this to you. You should never disregard warnings, as they often are indicators of undefined behavior.

Either use e.g. [`fputc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputc) or use the correct format string to print a character.

---

The second problem, is that you don't loop enough times for the sorting/merging to be complete, as well as you never check for the end of either input.

Answer (score 0):

at main
  change to

```
fprintf(fp_one, "%s", arr);//to prevent malfunction when '%' is included
fprintf(fp_two, "%s", brr);
fclose(fp_one);//to determine the output of the file.
fclose(fp_two);//Also Close to open the file in the merge_sort function.

merge_sort(num);
```

`merge_sort` change to

```
void merge_sort(int num){

    FILE *fp1,*fp2,*fp3;
    int point_one=0, point_two=0;
    char a[num], b[num];

    fp1=fopen("arr.txt","r");
    fp2=fopen("brr.txt","r");
    fp3=fopen("result.txt","w");

    fscanf(fp1, "%s", a);
    fscanf(fp2, "%s", b);
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    while(a[point_one] && b[point_two]){//Data of both is valid
        if(a[point_one]>b[point_two]){
            fprintf(fp3, "%c", b[point_two++]);
        } else {
            fprintf(fp3, "%c", a[point_one++]);
        }
    }
    if(a[point_one]){//There is a rest.
        fprintf(fp3, "%s", &a[point_one]);
    }
    if(b[point_two]){
        fprintf(fp3, "%s", &b[point_two]);
    }

    fclose(fp3);
}
```